# selecting XML data, returning incomplete output

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, select

[where are there red dots, missing the rest of XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAWTv.png)

I cannot find any solution...its the same even if I am using SQL developer
or selecting from sqlplus via cmd. Its local database.

[Here complete, creating table, inserting into and selecting XML, which returns incomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGuiW.png)

Comment: Can you provide your code and a sample of the input?  SO has a handy guide for providing [good sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) data.

Comment: Please put code, data and results into your question as formatted text rather than images. Some people are not able to view the images, and even for those that can it's usually a lot easier to read proper text - and it also allows your code to be copied, run and modified to find a solution. You should have [seen a message about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/266304) before you posted your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clients (looks like SQL*Plus and SQL Developer respectively in your images) only show the first 80 characters of long, LOB and XMLType values.

You can change that with the [`set long` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088) which works in both clients; e.g. `set long 1000`. You'll need to use a value large enough for the longest value you have;  but note the memory requirements - don't set it much higher than you actually need.